# почему результат выходит некорректным?

Tags: c#, linq, select, replace, split

Помогите разобраться, почему результат выходит некорректным. На выходе в слове "eyes" две большие буквы

```
string s = "my eyes"; 
var z = string.Join(" ", s.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Replace(x[0],Char.ToUpper(x[0]))));
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что не сложно догадаться, но почему вы не написали, что именно должно получиться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну потому что вы заменяете в слове **все** буквы `e` на `E`. Правильно можно решить эту задачу, например, так:

```
var z = string.Join(" ", s.Split(' ').Select(x => Char.ToUpper(x[0]) + x.Substring(1)));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось